# What if I see someone, like Nick Craver, doing something bad?

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

... like messing up the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)?

> #### What if I see someone doing something bad?
>
> I have a log file being written by another process which I want to watch for changes. Each time a change occurrs I'd like to read the new data in to do some processing on it.
>
> What's the best way to do this? I was hoping there'd be some sort of hook from the PyWin32 library. I've found the `win32file.FindNextChangeNotification` function but have no idea how to ask it to watch a specific file.
>
> If anyone's done anything like this I'd be really grateful to hear how...
>
> **[Edit]** I should have mentioned that I was after a solution that doesn't require polling.
>
> **[Edit]** Curses! It seems this doesn't work over a mapped network drive. I'm guessing windows doesn't 'hear' any updates to the file the way it does on a local disk.

The text seems to be plagiarized from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/182197/4751173), and all other help center links (on all SE sites) seem to be affected as well.

Comment: Entire network is affected

Comment: All the help center links are doing this; looks like a post cache leaking? http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics, for example

Comment: Nick Craver tweet in 3 ... 2 ...

Comment: @Bart [poor Nick](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/840179864938377216)

Comment: Nick has been notified and is fixing.

Comment: @Oded should I change the title to *What if I see someone, like Nick Craver, doing something bad?*?

Comment: Seems appropriate.

Comment: What if I see someone, like Nick Carver, doing something bad? 
Feel relieved that if the programmers on Stack Overflow can make mistakes, it's not so bad that I do too. :D

Comment: To answer the title of the question: "Just let him do it, it is the only way he will learn I'm afraid" :P

Comment: not my fault (spin the wheel)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

So I refactored the logging of the mass rebake route for HTTPS-ing help center articles and I moved a critical variable. The one that says which site to get the article from.

Good news: logging is really awesome
Bad news: all the help articles are from the wrong sites

...a new build is going up that will restore all of these. ETA: ~10 minutes.

Edit: fix complete, everything you saw was an illusion.

Edit 2: Since I'm a giver, here's the fix commit, and I promise not to commit any more code this week:

[image]

Comment: I'm now intrigued what site runs help answers like *If you do db:schema:load you will loose all your data!* :-D

Comment: @MartijnPieters https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22If+you+do+db%3Aschema%3Aload+you+will+loose+all+your+data!%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=tizDWJ2RNrKk8weX46KYDQ

Comment: @Glorfindel: [deleted answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/242124/100297). So the help articles are from answer posts, not the help center.

Comment: @MartijnPieters all help articles from [*all sites*](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) seem to be taken from (relatively old) SO posts.

Comment: I wish I could screw up this badly in my job and get a badge for it.

Comment: Yeah. All I ever get is badgered. :(

Comment: Half tempted to fix the spelling in that answer. It's a bit loose.

Comment: I am sorry, I should really have written more unit tests around the help center! /ducks

Answer (score 175):

Here's a couple of gems, from this brief and gloriously underappreciated moment, preserved for posterity:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[From chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5845745#5845745):

[image]

---

[image]

---

With credit to [Sasha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/252301/sasha) for [the capture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292172/hey-whats-with-the-help-pages)...

> [image]

---

[image: from Worldbuilding]

Comment: Sometimes I really miss the bounty function on Meta.

Comment: This should come back for April Fool's day.

Comment: Holy cow, the solution to the review problem.

Comment: This is what Cygwin is for, you know.

Comment: Curious to know if other metas have their owns preserved too!

Comment: `Just vote against McCain and the Republicans` Goddamnit, Joel.