# A whole text from triage review can't be found in original question revisions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review-queues, triage

I just stumbled upon a very weird situation.

I was going through the Review queue, when I got this review:

[image]

I first thought this was an audit, and I wanted to make sure, so I clicked on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167507/how-to-make-selected-text-bold-with-javascript-jquery-angularjs), and to my surprise, all that text from the review is not there.

I checked the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49167507/revisions) and here's another surprise. All that text is not there, not even in a single revision.

Note that when you visit the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19041744) link now, you won't see that text anymore.

What happened there? How did that text disappear and can't be found in a revision? Is that a bug, or that's something normal if someone edited his question right away before getting any view?

Comment: Text here: [**Anne Hathaway** *(nominated by FrB.TG )* is an American actress and singer...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Featured_content)

Comment: Wikipedia found a way to infiltrate SO with articles!

Comment: Sometimes spammers copy-paste Wikipedia entries, then insert their spam links in the content. I guess this text came from such a post, that was deleted as spam. So it probably _was_ an audit, but something got messed up with the post IDs.That's my guess, anyway.

Comment: If the post is edited within a 5-minute grace period, the new content replaces the old content without generating a separate new revision. So it's possible that the content was there just briefly and then got replaced by a quick follow-up edit. How it could then end up in the review queue is still a mystery to me, though.

Comment: Maybe [Nick Craver was doing something bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345280/4751173)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a lot of editing going on with that post.

In addition to the edits shown in the revision history, the author made **four** additional edits in the grace period following the third revision to the post: two prior to you opening the post for review and two more in between the period when you loaded the review and when you loaded the revision history. That makes three edits in total that could've introduced this odd bit of text in time for you to see it, and two more that could've removed it without resulting in a permanent addition to the revision history.

Given the first comment on the question (which preceded all of the edits) was "Show us your code", my guess is the author was attempting to paste in his code... And forgot what they had in their clipboard. Upon realizing what they'd done, the author then frantically edited to try to fix the problem, eventually resulting in the revision that you see as [Revision #3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49167507/timeline#history_da273df0-890e-4caa-8739-83401398d834).

Note that the automatic comment for that revision adds considerable weight to this theory: *"added 1459 characters in body; edited title"* - the revision as seen now definitely does *not* add 1459 characters; indeed, it reduces the body to a single short sentence. This is consistent with pasting a large amount of text followed by a hurried edit to remove that same text.

Comment: I guess this explains it all, and it's not a "bug" after all. It was just a lucky shot opening the review before he edits his text. Thank you Shog9.